# Import data from a txt file to sagemath and plot it

Tags: python, list, sage

I have data in a 'txt' file of the form

```
                       2     ;      4
                       3     ;      -8
                       5     ;       4
                    next prime      ...
```

So I am trying to import this data as a sequence (a_p)_{p, prime} to sagemath in order to plot it.

So I wrote the following code in 'file.sage'

```
a = open('/home/user/tmp/DataFile', 'r')

ap=[]
line=a.readline()
while(line !=''): 
    b=line.split(';')
    ap.append(integer(b[1]))
    line=f.readline()
```

But the problem is the list 'ap' is not indexed only by prime numbers, which hardens the task of plotting the function f(x):=cardinality of {p\le x : a_p,  satisfies some constraints }. So, I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're exactly having a problem with (the mathematical notations are unreadable and not explained properly). are you having issues with reading the file? 
a much better way to read files in python is: `ap = []
with open('/home/user/tmp/DataFile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ap.append(line.split(";")[1])
ap = list(map(int,ap))`

but this only gives you a single list like [4,-8,4]
how do you want to plot these numbers? can you provide an example of (x,y) values in your plot?

Comment: sorry about the code, it's not formatted properly in the comments, but I think you should be able to understand it

Comment: @OM222O Thank you for your comment, I would like to plot the counting function of primes p up a real number x such that ap[p] for example divisible by an integer s.  So I would like ap satisfies ap[2]=4 and ap[3]=-8 , ap[5]=4...

Comment: I'm not sure how the counting function works because 2 is the first prime number (not sure what the other 4 primes are or how there are -8 primes?) but either way, from what you said, I think you may need to look into using a dictionary rather than a list:
`ap = {} ... prime, num = line.split(";") ... ap[prime] = num`

Comment: @OM222O A prime number is an integer that has exactly two positive divisors, namely 1 and itself.   So, the counting function works as follows it takes a real number x as an argument and then runs over all prime numbers less than or equal to x and checks if ap[p] satisfies the condition ap[p]%s==0 it will be counted. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (taking some code and ideas from comments from @OM2220):

```
ap = {}
with open('/path/to/DATA.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        p,q = line.strip().split(';')
        ap[int(p)] = int(q)
list_plot(ap)
```

Then `ap` will be a dictionary with keys taken from the left column (prime numbers, in  this case), values the right column. Then in Sage you can do `list_plot(ap)`.